# Programs for graphing quadratic surfaces

Tags: surfaces, online-resources

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question - if not, please direct me to the proper place!
Either way, I am taking a course in Calc III. I need to graph surfaces in $ℝ^3$. Are there any online programs for this?

Comment: Mathematica is a great resource if you have access to it. If not, WolframAlpha can be helpful and has much the same functionality without the cost. Before Mathematica I used to often use WinPlot, which is free software and got the job done much of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you were looking for was a 2D surface plot, the plot was actually displaced in 3D with a leveling surface or 2D with a color gradient. The plot of a 3D function was somewhat complicated, which, with 3 parameter arguments and 1 output, was actually a 4D plots, which was usually done with 3D space with 1D color.

Mathematica could do the trick. However, more sophisticated programming language such as  Matlab or python could provided better visual.

Comment: Thanks! I used TI's computer software - they have a trial and the ti nspire did a fine job